# undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER'

Tags: php, mysql, constants

I have installed WAMP server on my local machine and I have written php script to insert record into the database, but I'm getting the following error-

***Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in C:\wamp\www\test_services\db_connect.php on line *32****

following is my **db_config code**

```
    <?php 

    define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
    define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password
    define('DB_DATABASE', "test_db"); // database name
    define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
    ?>

Here is my **db_connect.php code**

   <?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT 
{

    // constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct()
    {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() 
    {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() 
    {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

Please help.. Thank you..!

Comment: You are showing the code from the wrong file. You need to show the code from `db_connect.php`, not the code including it.

Comment: Line 32 is `if ($result)`. There is no way that is giving you the error `Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER`.

Comment: **Obligatory suggestion**, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @John Conde Sorry my mistake..! Please see the updated question.!

Comment: `db_connect.php` is missing a `require_once 'db_config.php';`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are showing the correct file. The problem is in db_connect.php. It is very likely that that file does not include db_config.php, i.e:

`require_once 'path/to/db_config.php';`

Edit: Does db_config.php actually live in the same directory as db_connect.php? Your code suggests that it does, which may be incorrect?

Edit: What happens if you put $var = 'hello' in db_config.php, and then print $var in db_connect.php after you include it, do you see 'hello'? Just to clarify you are connecting with the file..

Comment: I have created one folder called "test_services" in "www" folder and have written all php scripts their..